# Rows order in SQLite Database (iOS)

Tags: ios, sqlite, indexing, row

I have a database with a table called 'connection', for simplicities' sake, let's say I only have one column which is called 'rowName'. Now let's say I add a row with rowName = a; now I add a row with rowName = q, and lastly I add a row with rowName = w (letters are completely random). Now, I irritate thru the results with the statement:

```
    NSString * queryStatements = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT rowName,  FROM tableName"];
```

and using the code:

```
NSMutableArray * rows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //create a new array
sqlite3_stmt * statement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseHandle, [queryStatements UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW){
           NSString * rowName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String : (char*) sqlite_column_text(statement, 1)];
[rows addObject : connection];
} sqlite3_finalize(statement_;
}
```

In the array rows, will the object at index 0 be rowName = a, and at index 1 rowName=q, and at index 2 rowName = w? or will it be random? Is there a way to make it not-random?

Also, if i delete a row, will it have any affect on the other rows order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never depend on a sort order from your database. Always specify one if it is required.

```
SELECT rowName FROM tableName order by rowName
```

gives you the data sorted by rowName. If you need a different order, you need another column.

You can also sort your NSArray if need be.

What sort order are you looking for?

Comment: can i put a row of type DATE in the order by argument?

Comment: Yes. Technically SQLite doesn't have a date [data type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), but assuming you did the appropriate conversion when populating the database, you should be fine.

Comment: If you are relying on sqlite in your app, you may want to check out FMDB on github by Gus Muller. It provides a nice objective c wrapper around all those sqlite c functions.  and btw - totally agree with @terry wilcox on the "order by suggestion" - try to avoid using column indexes when possible.